# Simple but gives error--- Replace carriage return with a comma JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this below values in a javascript variable named 'data'

```
"Order","Id","Comment","Id_type"
"6","12321","www","Industry"
"4","32321","www","country"
```

There are carriage returns after every line. how could i replace it with a comma ??

I tried using the regex but it gives me error in chrome saying

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /
```

Here is the code i use to replace carriage return with comma. Pls advice.

```
data= data.replace(/\r/g,',');
```

Comment: The code you give on the last line doesn't give any errors for me. Also you'll probably want something like `/\r\n|\n/g` since newlines can come in two forms. Are you sure you're showing the line that gives the error? What's the simplest code to produce this error? What browser are you using?

Comment: Also can't reproduce the error.  Can you provide an [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); snippets or fiddles are pretty standard for javascript.

Comment: @adamdc78,
 i guess it gives an error only while using chrome ? i am using chrome.....

Comment: I'm using Chrome 44.0.2403.130 m.  What's in your console after running [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juhqs4da/)?

Comment: @adamdc78
This is soo strange. the jsfiddle gives me right output... i.e. a,b,c,d
I dont know why i am getting an error while working on my code. :(

Comment: Work up your own fiddle with the minimal amount needed to repro your problem lets us play around with it.

Comment: @adamdc78

Heres the strange part. i checked the console for errors. Then i thought of checking the sources tab there. 
It shows as this code below. i cannot see \r there. instead it goes to new line and shows /g, ","); in new line. 
data = data.replace(/
/g, ",");

Comment: @adamdc78
so basically it shows data = data.replace(/ /g, ","); instead of data = data.replace(/\r/g,","); It literally replaces /r in the code itself and goes to new line. thereby showing me whatever it is there after \r in the new line

Comment: `replace()` is a string method - is the content of your `data` variable a string?  If not, try something like `data.toString().replace(/\r\n|\n/g,',');`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a regex like this:

```
/[\r\n]/gm
```

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/sN2mX7/1)

Note that: **`m`** modifier: multi-line. Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)